# Using Apple's Transcription

Tags: ios, api, transcription

I was wondering if it is possible to use what Apple uses for Siri and Dictation in my own IOS app.

If this is possible, then how would I do it?

If Apple uses a 3rd party to transcribe audio files, then what is it? Does it have an API?

If Apple does their own transcribing and I cannot use it then... well then that's too bad.

Thanks a lot in advance for any responses. All are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the user taps the microphone button on a system-provided keyboard and speaks, you can access the result by implementing [the dictation-related methods of the `UITextInput` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInput_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009415-CH1-SW59). The iOS SDK doesn't provide any other access to the speech recognition system. You can't feed it your own audio file for interpretation.

The OS X SDK provides an `NSSpeechRecognizer` class. Maybe someday that will come to iOS.